# MySQL / React Application - TypeError: .map is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, reactjs

Im working on a react application using MySQL.

On my page which includes a list of serveral cars from my database i got the following error:

```
Server Error
TypeError: fahrzeugData.map is not a function

This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
Source
.next\server\pages\fahrzeuge.js (34:24) @ FahrzeugList

  32 | </thead>
  33 | <tbody className={styles.tbody}>
> 34 |   {fahrzeugData.map((fzData, index) => (
     |                ^
  35 |     <tr key={index}>
  36 |       <td className={styles.th}>{index + 1}</td>
  37 |       <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.brutto}</td>
Call Stack
Function.getInitialProps
.next\server\pages\_document.js (150:43)
```

My js file looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import styles from "../styles/FahrzeugList.module.css";
import axios from "axios";
function FahrzeugList({ fahrzeugData }) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const deleteFahrzeug = async (id) => {
    let fahrzeugliste_t5 = await axios.delete(`http://localhost:3000/api/fahrzeug/${id}`);
    router.push("/fahrzeuge");
  };
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <table className={styles.table}>
        <thead className={styles.thead}>
          <tr>
            <th className={styles.th}>FahrzeugId</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>brutto</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>erstzulassung</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>fahrzeugnummer</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>kilometer</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>modelljahr</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>netto</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>reserviert</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>sitzer</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>sonstiges</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>tuev</th>
            <th className={styles.th}>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody className={styles.tbody}>
          {fahrzeugData.map((fzData, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td className={styles.th}>{index + 1}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.brutto}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.erstzulassung}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.fahrzeugnummer}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.kilometer}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.modelljahr}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.netto}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.reserviert}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.sitzer}</td>
              <td className={styles.th}>{fzData.sonstiges}</td>
              <td>
                <button
                  className={styles.delete}
                  onClick={() => deleteFahrzeug(fzData.fz_id)}
                >
                  Delete
                </button>
                <button className={styles.update}>
                  <Link href={`/fahrzeuge/${fzData.fz_id}`}>Update</Link>
                </button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div className={styles.addFahrzeugCenter}>
        <button className={styles.addFahrzeug}>
          <Link href={`/addFahrzeug`}>addFahrzeug</Link>
        </button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default FahrzeugList;
```

Here is the js code where the FahrzeugList is used:

```
import FahrzeugList from "../components/FahrzeugList";
function fahrzeuge({ fahrzeugliste_t5 }) {
  console.log("fahrzeugliste_t5", fahrzeugliste_t5);
  return (
    <div>
      <FahrzeugList fahrzeugData={fahrzeugliste_t5} />
    </div>
  );
}

export async function getServerSideProps() {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/fahrzeug");
  const fahrzeugliste_t5 = await res.json();
  return {
    props: { fahrzeugliste_t5 },
  };
}

export default fahrzeuge;
```

And my database looks basically like this:
[image: database]

Adding new Cars to the list works perfectly from a different screen but displaying the list doesnt work. The Documentation for .map() function didnt help me.

Comment: What is the type of `fahrzeugData`?

Comment: Ok, but what is the type of `fahrzeugData`?

Comment: When i write:
 <div>
      <FahrzeugList fahrzeugData={[fahrzeugliste_t5]} />
    </div>
with [ ] the error is gone but no entries are shown

Comment: For one, `{fahrzeugliste_t5}` would be an object, which doesn't have a `map()` function. You might try mapping over its keys instead. But really, what exactly is in the variable? Have you logged it?

Comment: Can you console or look it over postman what is the format of your api response looks like once you get data from database?

Comment: Thanks for all your answers - im just dumb. It was actually about wrong sql querys where the table name was wrong. Thanks for the tip with postman.